# How to use sbt-scalabuff plugin with sbt 0.13?

Tags: scala, sbt, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use [sbt-scalabuff plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-scalabuff), but sbt keeps complaining that the plugin cannot be found.

The plugin documentation does not state out a resolver url, either. Is the plugin deprecated or my Scala version is not supported?

Details:

```
com.github.sbt:sbt-scalabuff:0.2 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
```

Here is my `plugins.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "net.sandrogrzicic" %% "scalabuff-runtime" % "1.3.6"

addSbtPlugin("com.github.sbt" %% "sbt-scalabuff" % "0.2")
```

Here is part of the stack trace:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.sbt#sbt-scalabuff;0.2: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:104)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:51)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:60)
    ...
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.sbt#sbt-scalabuff;0.2: not found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The sbt-scalabuff plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-scalabuff) does not have the plugin jar published to any known repository sbt could use for your configuration - `sbtVersion=0.13` and `scalaVersion=2.10`.

I also doubt the plugin supports sbt `0.13` (few attempts of mine failed miserably when I compiled the plugin myself to use the version).

It seems that your only options are to downgrade sbt to `0.12.4` or migrate the plugin to `0.13`.

Since the plugin has been published to the `Resolver.sbtPluginRepo("releases")` repository, i.e. http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases as http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.github.sbt/sbt-scalabuff/scala_2.10/sbt_0.12/ you will have to use the version of sbt.

Use the following in `project/sbt-scalabuff.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.sbt" %% "sbt-scalabuff" % "0.2")
```

You should then specify the version of sbt in `project/build.properties` as follows:

```
sbt.version=0.12.4
```

or just use [sbt-launch 0.12.4](http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.12.4/sbt-launch.jar).

When in sbt console, you can use the `scalabuff` task or the settings: `scalabuff-version`, `scalabuff-main` and `scalabuff-args`.

```
> sbt-version
[info] 0.12.4
> about
[info] This is sbt 0.12.4
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-scalabuff-test-project/}main
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.9.2
[info] Available Plugins: org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin, com.timushev.sbt.updates.UpdatesPlugin, scalabuff.ScalaBuffPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.9.2
> scalabuff-version
[info] 1.1.1
> help scalabuff
Generate Scala sources from protocol buffers definitions
> scalabuff-args
[info] List()
> scalabuff-main
[info] net.sandrogrzicic.scalabuff.compiler.ScalaBuff
```

See the [scalabuff.ScalaBuffPlugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-scalabuff/blob/master/src/main/scala/ScalaBuffPlugin.scala) object in the GitHub repository.

I also had to change the build object (as described in [the Usage section](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-scalabuff#usage)) to set up a project with the plugin to `import sbt._`:

```
import sbt._
import scalabuff.ScalaBuffPlugin._

object build extends Build {
  lazy val root = Project(
    "main",
    file("."),
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ scalabuffSettings
  ).configs(ScalaBuff)
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Another +1 for pointing to the repo url. I wasn't able to find this out.